# Pagination increment pages

Tags: php

A form showing different posts of user. Posts which is stored in database. Now the problem is the previous pagination works fine but the next pagination is incrementing 2 blank pages and url changes with that page. Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this code .?

php:

```
<?php 
        $limitr = ((($page*2)+1)-2)*$perpage; 


        $query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM final1 LIMIT {$limitr}, {$perpage}");
        $records = mysqli_fetch_all($query);

        $total = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total");
        $total = mysqli_fetch_assoc($total)['total'];

        $pages = ceil($total/$perpage);
        ?>

 <?php 
              if($page>1){
                ?>
                <a class="page-link" href="?page=<?php $pagep = $page -1; echo $pagep; ?>" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
                <?php
              }
              ?>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item">
              <?php 
              if($page<$pages){
                ?>
                <a class="page-link" href="?page=<?php $pagen = $page +1; echo $pagen; ?>">Next</a>
                <?php
              }
              ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM final1 LIMIT {$limitr}, {$perpage}");
```

The first parameter after the LIMIT the offset,, the second is how much records do you want.

But I'm not sure what are you calculating with limitr btw. If you already have which page do you want, it should be simply

```
LIMIT {($page-1)*perpage}, {$perpage}
```

Also, the database is unordered, so might miss some records or duplicate others, might wanna add some kind of ORDER BY option.

(SORRY, ORDERS ARE REVERSED WHEN USED WITH COMMA!)

Comment: kry Thanks for your answer .. $limitr show the even number of posts. and let me check if its working or not .

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_all() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\multiselect.php on line 300 error

Comment: Your SQL doesn't run properly, the query should give a result. Can you show me what message do you get when running the query in your database?

Comment: In your second query, the "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total" you are missing your table name.

Comment: @kry _"SORRY, ORDERS ARE REVERSED WHEN USED WITH COMMA!"_ -> then please edit your answer to correct the sentence _"The first parameter after the LIMIT shows how much info do you want, the second is the offset, or from where"_

Comment: That's why I said sorry, and left the original one. Normally you do it like LIMIT 50 OFFSET 60, which returns 50 records starting with the 60th one. However, if you write it like LIMIT 50, 60 it will give back 60 records, starting with the 50th. Linnea write it correctly first, and I badly corrected him/her/it. The original was the correct one, which is now in the answer.

Sorry, now I get what you meant. I need to read more carefully.